# VS2012 SSRS Cannot See Data Fields

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have a VS2012 SSRS report project with a shared data set. The data set is being created from a SQL Stored Proc. I used to use VS2008, and all of the available data fields would show below the data set, however, in VS2012 I cannot figure out how to get them to show. I've removed the data set, and added it back, I've completely removed the DataSource and added it back, nothing works.

The original report file was built in VS2008, and was converted to a VS2012 project. Not sure if this could be contributing to the problem.

Thank you.

[image: Here is what my Solution Explorer is currently showing]

Comment: If they are accessible by the report code, why do you want to display them in this area?

Comment: They don't seem accessible. I attempt to use them in an expression, and they error. Any existing field in the report works, when I try to use a new field (I've added a few new fields to the SQL) they don't work. However, when I run the SQL from the report, I can see all of my added fields. Something is odd.

Comment: It is also nice to see the available fields without going into the report properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen shot shows the Solution Explorer pane. Data Fields never appeared in this pane, in any version of SSRS.

I suspect what you are looking for is the Report Data Pane, which you should find on the View menu

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627528(v=sql.120).aspx